# How to fix the extremely laggy behavior of BQ Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris, m10

I recently purchased the **Aquaris M10** and I am experiencing extremely laggy behaviour. When I use the browser, every time I leave a website, when I return, even the next second, it reloads it. Firefox with mouse and keyboard will not do that, so it is not a memory issue. When scrolling, at random it will go fully to the other direction (when scrolling down it will go to the top, when scrolling up it will go to the bottom). When I use a drawing app, Doodle, the drawing is always a stream of dots, never a smooth line.

These are just some of the problems I have encountered. Trying to find answers online, something very easy when using regular Ubuntu, will just not work, I either find news about Ubuntu touch or solutions for the regular version that do not apply.

I understand that it is a very new product, but I cannot work with it. The question is: what can I do? I want to help with the lagginess, however I can.

Comment: Looks like the tabs on the default browser was a design decision as it had a different behavior before the last update. This was more than likely to save processing power or memory, I don't really agree with it but a lot of mobile browsers do something similar albeit usually with a nicer implementation which doesn't reload the page every time.

Comment: is your browser up to date?

Comment: For comparison; using Doodle on HD, I see dots if traced quickly (approx >5cm/sec w/fingertip), but no dots if more slowly. Might expect differences between HD (1280x800) and FHD (1920x1200).

Comment: What ota version do you have installed.
Try to update to the newest one.

Comment: I actually bought one of the very first M10 FHD Ubuntu Tablet by Aquaris. I experienced all of what you described o_O  (?!?) and a few buckets of bugs, untested apps, missing apps, incomplete apps and strange hangups, not to mention an wholly ineffectual BT. I lived through an update and ... returned the tablet without looking back.

Comment: I also have an M10 and on the whole, I am very pleased with it. I also experience the issues you mentioned with the default browser. I have posted a question on here about it and will be raising a bug for it in Launchpad. I also noticed the scrolling issue. Raise it in Launchpad and hopefully this will get addressed in the next builds. What other issues have you experienced?

Comment: which one do you have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it appears to be about bugs with the default browser included with the BQ Aquaris M10 rather than Ubuntu

Comment: closure of this looks like ubuntu censure, It was very good question. I also would be glad to help ubuntu but it is overhelmingly difficult to get into development, tweaking the os/apps. It is difficult to get SDK running. last time I tried on fresh ubuntu install it didnt worked. Tbjweaking the os, particulary for people like me, without any android background, is close to impossible. The very detailed manual how to do most tweaking which we do normaly on desktop (like kernel rebuilding) would be really appreciated, as lots of stuff is not working out of box.